taylor expansion and little o notation
I'm trying to prove de moivre-laplace theorem using sterling's formula and taylor expansion. However I'm unsure how to proceed from now on.
I know the following:
$$
log \frac{p^xq^{n-x}}{(x/n)^x(1-x/n)^{n-x}} = -np(1+z\sqrt{\frac{q}{np}})log(1+z\sqrt{\frac{q}{np}}-nq(1-z\sqrt{\frac{p}{nq}})log(1-z\sqrt{\frac{p}{nq}})
$$
where
$$
z = \frac{x-np}{\sqrt{npq}}
$$
Therefore I am using the following Taylor Expansion:
$$
(1+x)log(1+x) = x + \frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x^3}{6} + o(x^3)
$$
And I arrived here:
$$
log \frac{p^xq^{n-x}}{(x/n)^x(1-x/n)^{n-x}} = -\frac{z^2}{2} + \frac{z^3(q-p)}{6\sqrt{npq}} - np * o((z\sqrt{\frac{q}{np}})^3) - nq * o((-z\sqrt{\frac{p}{nq}})^3)
$$
And the thing is the last part should be $o(1)$ like the following:
$$
\frac{z^3(q-p)}{6\sqrt{npq}} - np * o((z\sqrt{\frac{q}{np}})^3) - nq * o((-z\sqrt{\frac{p}{nq}})^3) = o(1)
$$
I'm stuck here and have little knowledge about little o notation. Thank you for everyone tries to help me.
